# Unity 5 MultiPlayer NetworkTransport.Send

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, unity-networking

So I'm new to Unity and need to make a multiplayer game where I could sync clients with the interface on the Game server, I've created a Client and a server and the client do connect to the server but the problem is that it couldn't send messages, all that server receive is Null

I'm running the server as an application and the client need to be a WebGL

**This is my Server.cs :**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public class server : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 2000;
    private const string SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.8";
    private const int SERVER_PORT = 8999;
    private const int SERVER_WEB_PORT = 8998; 
    private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 400000;
    
    private int reliablechannelid;
    private int unreliablechannelid;

    private int hostId;
    private int webHosted;

    private byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    private bool isInit;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GlobalConfig config = new GlobalConfig();
        NetworkTransport.Init(config);

        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();
        reliablechannelid = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        unreliablechannelid = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTIONS);

        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, SERVER_PORT);
        webHosted = NetworkTransport.AddWebsocketHost(topo, SERVER_WEB_PORT);
        isInit = true;

    }



    //This function is called when data is sent
    void OnData(int hostId, int connectionId, int channelId, byte[] data, int size, NetworkError error)
    {
        //Here the message being received is deserialized and output to the console
        Stream serializedMessage = new MemoryStream(data);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string message = formatter.Deserialize(serializedMessage).ToString();

        //Output the deserialized message as well as the connection information to the console
        Debug.Log("OnData(hostId = " + hostId + ", connectionId = "
            + connectionId + ", channelId = " + channelId + ", data = "
            + message + ", size = " + size + ", error = " + error.ToString() + ")");

        Debug.Log("data = " + message);
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        {
            if (!isInit)
            {
                return;
            }



            int outHostId;
            int outConnectionId;
            int outChannelId;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int receivedSize;
            byte error;

            //Set up the Network Transport to receive the incoming message, and decide what type of event
            NetworkEventType eventType = NetworkTransport.Receive(out outHostId, out outConnectionId, out outChannelId, buffer, buffer.Length, out receivedSize, out error);

            switch (eventType)
            {
                //Use this case when there is a connection detected
                case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
                    {
                        //Call the function to deal with the received information
                        Debug.Log("Connected");
                        break;
                    }

                //This case is called if the event type is a data event, like the serialized message
                case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
                    {
                        //Call the function to deal with the received data
                        OnData(outHostId, outConnectionId, outChannelId, buffer, receivedSize, (NetworkError)error);
                        break;
                    }

                case NetworkEventType.Nothing:
                    break;

                default:
                    //Output the error
                    Debug.LogError("Unknown network message type received: " + eventType);
                    break;
            }
        }

       
       

    }
}
```

**This is my Client.cs :**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
public class client : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 2000;
    private const string SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.7";
    private const int SERVER_PORT = 8999;
    private const int SERVER_WEB_PORT = 8998;
    private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 400000;
    private int connectionId;
  
    private int reliablechannelid;
    private int unreliableChannelId;

    private int hostId;
    bool ok;

    private byte error;
    // private byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    private bool isConnected;
    public string Msg = "test";
    public byte[] buffer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Connect()
    {
        GlobalConfig config = new GlobalConfig();
        NetworkTransport.Init(config);

        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();
        reliablechannelid = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
       
        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTIONS);

        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, 0);



#if UNITY_WEBGL

        connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostId, SERVER_IP, SERVER_WEB_PORT, 0, out error);
        Debug.Log((NetworkError)error);
        Debug.Log("connectionId=  "+connectionId);



#else
        connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostId, SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT, 0, out error);
        Debug.Log((NetworkError)error);
        Debug.Log("connectionId=  " + connectionId);
#endif


    }

    //This is the function that serializes the message before sending it
    void SendMyMessage(string textInput)
    {
        byte error;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        Stream message = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        //Serialize the message
        formatter.Serialize(message, textInput);

        //Send the message from the "client" with the serialized message and the connection information
        NetworkTransport.Send(hostId, connectionId, reliablechannelid, buffer, (int)message.Position, out error);

        //If there is an error, output message error to the console
        if ((NetworkError)error != NetworkError.Ok)
        {
            Debug.Log("Message send error: " + (NetworkError)error);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        SendMyMessage("heyyyyy");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution ,
i just added

```
NetworkTransport.Connect(hostId, SERVER_IP, SERVER_WEB_PORT, 0, out error);
```

to my server too , i didn't know that server need to be connected too
hope this will help someone